# RedHat Anaconda and groups

Tags: rhel, yum, dnf, installer-anaconda

I need to enumerate the packages within Anaconda installation groups (`@core`, `@Desktop`, `@admin-tools`, `@base`, `@system-tools`, etc).

I've tried using the source for Anaconda, and I've also looked through many of the "comps" XML and SQLite files on the DVD ISO, but I'm failing to find the group names (either short or long name used by yum/dnf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yum grouplist
dnf grouplist
```

Return the group package names.  Quote those with embedded spaces (e.g. `security tools`).

It is useful to add the `hidden` argument to expose packages like `core`, normally excluded from a group list:

```
yum|dnf group list hidden
```

With `yum` adding the `ids` argument will add the shorter name (in parenthesis) used by Anaconda (and Kickstart):

```
yum grouplist ids
```

With `dnf` this shorter name is added when the verbose option is employed:

```
dnf -v grouplist
```

This syntax also applies to `yum` although the addition of the `ids` string may be more intuitive.

To see the packages that comprise a group, use:

```
yum groupinfo [groupname]
```

For example:

```
yum groupinfo core
dnf groupinfo core
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me pointed in the right direction.  Before I accept the answer can you double-check and correct a few discrepancies I found on my testing RHEL 6.8 with yum-3.2.29-75.el6_8.noarch system.  First, the "yum grouplist ids" doesn't work, but "yum -v grouplist" reports the short name as you mentioned.  Second using "yum groupinfo core" or "yum groupinfo base" (without the "@") works where adding the "@" reports an error "Warning: Group @core does not exist."

Comment: I don't currently have a RHEL server available.  I'm using CentOS 7.2 and Fedora 25.  With CentOS `yum` is version 3.4.3 and affixing `@` works for the groups you mentioned, but isn't necessary.  I have edited my response to remove it. it's Kickstart syntax that uses the `@` sigil to denote environmental group names.  In CentOS-7 `core` is a group within the environmental group `minimal`.  Again. for CentOS-7, `grouplist ids` is equivalent to `yum -v grouplist` which mimics exactly what's need for `dnf` (as with Fedora).